# JavaScript - Passing a callback function inside a self-invoking function

Tags: javascript, closures, self-invoking-function

I am trying to pass a `callback` function inside a `self-invoking function` in JavaScript but I get 'undefined' when `done` function is executed.

I read [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24103264/parent-function-variable-access-from-callback-and-inline-self-invoking-function) to write this code below:

```
function done() {
    console.log(dateFilter.getI());
    console.log(dateFilter.getF());
}

var dateFilter = (function(callback) {
    var _dInicio = new Date(), _d = new Date(),
        _dFim = new Date(_d.setMonth(new Date().getMonth() - 1));
    return {
        getI: function() { return _dInicio; },
        getF: function() { return _dFim; },
        setI: function(d) { _dInicio = d; },
        setF: function(d) { _dFim = d; }
    }, callback();

 })(done);
```

Maybe I am using the [comma operator](http://es5.github.io/#x11.14) wrong, but I think this should work. Someone could point me where i am misunderstanding something?

Comment: `done` doesn't return anything. Are you at least getting the logs for the dateFilter?

Answer (score 3):

You're calling the `done` function after a `return`, further, you're not passing the param `dateFilter`.

```
return { -> return before calling callback `function`.
    getI: function() { return _dInicio; },
    getF: function() { return _dFim; },
    setI: function(d) { _dInicio = d; },
    setF: function(d) { _dFim = d; }
}, callback( );
            ^
            |_ Calling callback without param `dateFilter`
```

## Look at this code snippet

```js
function done(dateFilter) {
  console.log(dateFilter.getI());
  console.log(dateFilter.getF());
}

(function(callback) {
  var _dInicio = new Date(),
    _d = new Date(),
    _dFim = new Date(_d.setMonth(new Date().getMonth() - 1));

  callback({
    getI: function() {
      return _dInicio;
    },
    getF: function() {
      return _dFim;
    },
    setI: function(d) {
      _dInicio = d;
    },
    setF: function(d) {
      _dFim = d;
    }
  });

})(done);
```

See? now is printing the values.

Comment: I see, that works, but this way I can't access dateFilter inner functions out of `done function` scope, can I?

Comment: @AlexandreMiziara I don’t understand.  Which inner functions?

Comment: all the functions inside `dateFilter` (`getI, setI, etc.`)

Comment: Your snippet does assign `var dateFilter = undefined`, as the IIFE doesn't return anything.

Comment: @AlexandreMiziara they are available because were passed as param to your `done` function.

Answer (score 2):

Two reasons this cannot work:

- You are returning the result of `callback` with your comma operator, but `done` does not return anything
- You are trying to use `dateFilter` during the IIFE initialisation of `dateFilter` - it is not yet assigned the return value

There is absolutely no reason to use a callback with an IIFE. Just write

```
var dateFilter = (function() {
    var _dInicio = new Date(), _d = new Date(),
        _dFim = new Date(_d.setMonth(new Date().getMonth() - 1));
    return {
        getI: function() { return _dInicio; },
        getF: function() { return _dFim; },
        setI: function(d) { _dInicio = d; },
        setF: function(d) { _dFim = d; }
    };
}());

console.log(dateFilter.getI());
console.log(dateFilter.getF());
```

Comment: Actually I need to execute a function after ensure that `dateFilter` has been executed, that's why I tryied using `callback`. Should I use promies instead?

Comment: There is nothing asynchronous in here, so just placing it after the `IIFE` will ensure that it has been run.

Comment: *If* the initialisation process was asynchronous, then yes, use promises.

Answer (score 1):

You're **really** close. Your hunch about the comma operator is correct. And I think there's a better way to wire up your `done()` callback so that the code is a bit more robust, and the order in which things happen is a bit clearer.

First, let's look at the `return` statement. All return statements do **two** things (evaluate the return value, then return it), but because of the comma, this one is doing **three**, in the following order:

1. Evaluating the object literal `{ getI:... }`
2. evaluating `callback()`, which means **calling** `callback()`
3. returning the return value of `callback()`, since the comma operator returns it's second operand.

So, note that `callback()` actually gets called **before** your function returns, so it happens **before** `dateFilter` has a value. (And, even if it **did** have a value, it would be the return value from `callback()`, which is undefined.)

And I think there's another aspect of your code here that I think is worth a look. Callbacks typically take **parameters**. The simplest way to think of it is: Instead of returning a value, you pass it to the callback.

In general, code is easier to read and debug if you pass parameters instead of side-effecting shared variables.

I just made one change to your code, and it's working:

```js
function done(dateFilter) {
    console.log(dateFilter.getI());
    console.log(dateFilter.getF());
}

(function(callback) {
    var _dInicio = new Date(), _d = new Date(),
        _dFim = new Date(_d.setMonth(new Date().getMonth() - 1));
    callback({
        getI: function() { return _dInicio; },
        getF: function() { return _dFim; },
        setI: function(d) { _dInicio = d; },
        setF: function(d) { _dFim = d; }
    });

 })(done);
```

So, what did I do?

- Instead of side-effecting the `dateFilter` value, I pass it directly to `callback`.

This means: no comma operator in the `return` statement, and no need to side-effect the `dateFilter` global value. (`dateFilter` is now a parameter to `done` isntead.)

I hope that clarifies things for you. Cheers!

Comment: That clarifies a lot. I wasn't seeing how the order of the things was beeing executed before. Thanks for your answer. Now I understant better how callback and comma operator can work together.