# Are parent function variables reliably accessible in a callback function?

Tags: javascript, callback

I've seen a couple of questions that bear resemblance to mine ([[1]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31793940/can-callback-functions-access-parent-function-variables), [[2]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24103264/parent-function-variable-access-from-callback-and-inline-self-invoking-function)), but these seem to not quite hit what I'm after.

Example code:

```js
function test(argument1) {
  sendToServer(argument2, function(callbackArgument1) {
    // Accessing argument1 here
  });
}
```

In the above example, I would like to access an argument (`argument1`) inside a callback function. Of course this is possible by passing `argument1` as an argument in `sendToServer()`, and pass it around in that function, and eventually send it back in the callback, similar to `callbackArgument1`, but with more than 1 callback, this quickly gets extremely overwhelming and makes code very hard to read, especially if `argument1` is not required inside the `sendToServer()` code.

I have tested this setup, where I added an artificial 2 second delay on the server side code, with the following setup:

```js
function test(argument1) {
  sendToServer(function() {
    console.log(argument1);
  });
}
```

My fear would be that calling `test()` in rapid succession would overwrite `argument1`, so `test()` is called quickly enough, all the callbacks end up with `argument1` being the same.

When I tested it however by calling `test("cb1");` and `test("cb2");` in quick succession, it returned `"cb1"` after 2 seconds, and 2 more seconds later, it returned `"cb2"`. Although this is pretty conclusive, something feels very off to me, and I feel like this would not work at all in other programming languages, and would be heavily frowned upon.

So: Is it acceptable to access arguments from (or variables defined inside) the parent function (`test()`  in my case) in a callback?

Comment: Yes, it's reliable. Each call to `test` gets its own execution environment with its own lexical environment object that the identifiers within it (parameters, variables) exist within. Any function created within `test` has a link to that environment object, and the environment survives as long as any of those functions survives (even when `test` returns). Different calls to `test` get their *own* environments, so there's no cross-talk.

Comment: See the linked question's answers or my blog post [*Closures are not complicated*](http://blog.niftysnippets.org/2008/02/closures-are-not-complicated.html) (some of the spec terminology is outdated now, but the gist is unchanged).

Comment: Note that if `argument1` is a reference to an object, and something modifies one or more of that object's properties, naturally your code will see those modifications.